# Use of pointer to pop from circular array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to dequeue a circular array from an arbitrary point by using a routine for dequeue. I want to do that by a pointer , is that possible?

```
unsigned char *ptrDisc, len;
unsigned char Queue[50]; //my circular array
unsigned char Pckt[20]; //array where I put my extracted data
unsigned char ind_pop, ind_push; //index from circular array

len=10; //10byte to extract
ptrDisc = (Queue+10); //first position from I want to extract data

Dequeue(ptrDisc, len, Pckt, ind_pop, ind_push);
```

I want that Pckt will be full with my "len" data, but I can't get data. Is y Pckt array is full of my data, if I use as first parameter "QUeue". Perhaps the answer is "Not possible because it is a circular array" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question, do you mean a circular array as in a circular linked list? Arrays are aligned on a fixed amount of storage no later than initialization of local variables within block scope at run time and stored in a data segment that can not change size.